# How to make a Wordpress website with multiple paths?

Tags: wordpress

I want to make a website which not only is `domain.com` but also has other websites in it such as `domain.com/path1`.

Is my only option to make new directories with fresh installs of Wordpress on my server, or is it possible for me to handle everything within one Wordpress installation?

Comment: Yes, Multisite is one option, the other -easier- a custom `wp-config.php` There's a q&a at [wordpress.se] on how to do the second one.

Comment: An alternative is to make Custom Post Types which are in subfolders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
1) Create A new path directory name with xxx 
2) transfer whole file in xxx directory 
3) Change your database in url domain.com to domain.com/xxx
```

> then you can access your web using this url **domain.com/xxx**